# How to use Ordinary Least Square (OLS) & Geographically Weighted Regression (GWR)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have managed to join the data set(xl. file) with a shapefile. I want to run these models, OLS and GWR in Arcmap, my problem is, I'm bit confuse about these fields, "Input Feature Class", "Output Feature Class", and "Input Features"?, what do I need to do in order to achieve this task?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your Question so that it provides a lot more details about what you have researched/tried and where you are stuck, please?

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly defined and explained in the Help.

[ArcGIS 10.2 GWR Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005p00000021000000)

[ArcGIS 10.2 OLS Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Ordinary_Least_Squares_OLS/005p00000022000000/)